# Differentation: Perimeter of a sector with given area (Edexcel A Level C2 Exercise 9C Q3)

Tags: derivatives

I'm stumped with an answer to a question regarding Differentation (in a book for Edexcel Core Mathematics 2):

> A sector of a circle has area $100 \text{cm}^2$. Show that the permimeter of this sector is given by the formula $P=2r+(200/r)$, $r > \sqrt{100/\pi}$.
>
> Find the minimum value for the perimeter of such a sector.

The answer is shown as:

> Perimeter $$P = 2r+r\theta \label{1}\tag{1}$$
>
> Area $A = (1/2)r^2\theta$
>
> But area is $100\text{cm}^2$, so
>
> $(1/2)r^2\theta = 100$
>
> $r\theta = 200/r$
>
> Substitute into equation \eqref{1} to give $$P = 2r + 200/r\label{2}\tag{2}$$
>
> and since area of circle > area of sector, $\pi r^2 > 100$, so $r >  \sqrt{100/\pi}$.
>
> $dP/dr = 2 - 200/r^2$
>
> So, for $dP/dr = 0$, $r = 10$
>
> Substitute into equation \eqref{2} to give $P = 20 + 20 = 40\text{cm}$.

I understand the answer up until the derivative function of the perimeter is given.

The original equation of the perimeter is $P = 2r + 200/r$, as shown in the question and proved in the workings.

I do not understand how the derivative function of $P = 2r + 200/r$ is $p'(r) = 2 - 200/r^2$. Can anyone help by walking through how the derivative equation is derived, please? I think I must be missing something obvious as I haven't had issues with other questions in the chapter. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$P(r) = 2r +\frac{200}{r}=2r^1+200r^{-1}$$
$$\frac{dP}{dr} =2\cdot 1r^{1-1}+200\cdot(-1)r^{-1-1}$$
$$=2r^0-200r^{-2}$$
$$=2-\frac{200}{r^2}$$

Comment: I'm guessing the second term is what tripped you up. Generally, for $p>0$, $$\frac{d}{dx}\left\{\frac a{x^p}\right\} = -\frac{ap}{x^{p+1}}$$ by similar reasoning (work it out!).

Comment: Yeah it was the second term, silly for me not to see it in retrospect - I'll blame it on being rusty after festive period! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

your function isn $$P(r)=2r+200r^{-1}$$ for the derivative we need the rule $$(x^n)'=nx^{n-1}$$ thus we have $$P'(r)=2+200(-1)r^{-2}$$

Comment: Thanks, both this and MPW's answer explains it.